# Create User profile with separate social media data

Tags: c#, api, interface, web-services

I am creating user profile logic for a blogging platform.  I have the `UserProfile` model and then two separate models, `UserSocialLink` and `SocialLinkType` to control the user's various social media contacts (i.e. Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc...).  I am looking for feed back on the execution of the methods used to `Add` new `UserProfiles`.  Is this the way you would handle it? Is there a better way? What are some of the issues you see with my methods (specifically in the service class)?

**The Models**

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
 }

public class UserSocialLink
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public int SocialLinkTypeID { get; set; }
    public string LinkValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual SocialLinkType SocialLinkType {get; set;}
}

public class SocialLinkType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LinkType { get; set; }
    public string URLFormat { get; set; }
}
```

**The Add Methods in The Service Class**

```
public class UserProfileService : IUserProfileService
{
    public UserProfile Add(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (userProfile == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("User Profile");

        userProfile.Created = now;
        userProfile.Updated = now;
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return userProfile;
    }

    public UserProfile AddSocialLink(string userName, UserSocialLink userSocialLink, string socialLinkType)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var userProfile = Get(userName);
        if (userProfile == null)
            throw new Exception("User Profile Not Found");
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var linkType = db.SocialLinkTypes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.LinkType.ToUpper() == socialLinkType.ToUpper());
            if (linkType == null)
                throw new Exception("Social Media Type Not Found");
            userSocialLink.Created = now;
            userSocialLink.Updated = now;
            userSocialLink.SocialLinkTypeID = linkType.Id;
            db.UserSocialLinks.Add(userSocialLink);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return userProfile;
         }
    }
}
```

> Related [GitHub Issue #14](https://github.com/comeallyouweary/api/issues/14)

Comment: Not a real answer, but shouldn't variable names be camelCase instead of PascalCase? PascalCase is generally reserved for container types (like a class). Just a thought :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition [RubberDuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/rubberduck)'s answer about the braces:

Inside the `AddSocialLink()` method you have this

> ```
> var userProfile = Get(userName);
> if (userProfile == null)
>     throw new Exception("User Profile Not Found");
> ```

Here, with the usage of `var`, it isn't obvious what datatype is assigned to userProfile. The methodname `Get` does not reflect anything to make it more clear.
Sure, Mr.Maintainer could assume, as this is the `UserProfileService`, that the return type would be a `UserProfile`, but it would be more explicit to add a `ExistUserProfile()` method which just returns a boolean.

```
private Boolean ExistUserProfile(String userName)
{
    UserProfile userProfile = Get(userName);
    return userProfile != null;
}
```

The `UserProfileService` class does violate the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as it is responsible to add, get etc `UserProfile` data and at least to **also** add `UserSocialLink` data.
This is also reflected clearly in the question title: "Create User profile with **separate** social media data".

Returning a `UserProfile` object from this method does not make any sense, as the code isn't changing any property of the retrieved userprofile.
A user of the `UserProfileService` class wouldn't expect that adding a `SocialLink` by calling the `AddSocilaLink()` method would return a `UserProfile` object.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public UserProfile AddSocialLink(string userName, UserSocialLink userSocialLink, string socialLinkType)
> ```

Shouldn't the `socialLinkType` be a property of the `UserSocialLink` class? It seems odd to me that the code has to pass a string along with the object in order to tell the method what type it is. That said, I really do like that you're checking the database to make sure the type is valid. Now that I think of it, why pass the user name as a string? Wouldn't it be a simpler API to pass a `UserProfile` in? At least, it would be more consistent for the dev using the `UserProfileService`.

---

This code is a great example of why we should all use proper indentation and braces around if statements.

> ```
> var linkType = db.SocialLinkTypes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.LinkType.ToUpper() == socialLinkType.ToUpper());
> if (linkType == null)
>     throw new Exception("Social Media Type Not Found");
> userSocialLink.Created = now;
> userSocialLink.Updated = now;
> userSocialLink.SocialLinkTypeID = linkType.Id;
> db.UserSocialLinks.Add(userSocialLink);
> db.SaveChanges();
> return userProfile;
> ```

At a glance, it looks like the `userSocialLink` only gets it's properties set `if (linkType == null)` and after an exception is thrown. Of course, this is ridiculous and not what is actually happening, but braces make that crystal clear to Mr. Maintainer.

```
var linkType = db.SocialLinkTypes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.LinkType.ToUpper() == socialLinkType.ToUpper());
if (linkType == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Social Media Type Not Found");
}
userSocialLink.Created = now;
userSocialLink.Updated = now;
userSocialLink.SocialLinkTypeID = linkType.Id;
db.UserSocialLinks.Add(userSocialLink);
db.SaveChanges();
return userProfile;
```

Comment: Braces, will be added. The `socialLinkType` is not part of the `UserSocialLink` because I didn't want to repeatedly store the word Facebook in the database. So `SocialLinkType` is a separate model. I don't think the developer should have to pass the entire `UserProfile` just to create a `UserSocialLink` especially when you can create multiple `UserSocialLinks` per profile.